# Limit of a Sequence with odd terms increasing even terms increasing

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2+x_n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show the limit exists and find its value.

Here we have a sequence with odd terms increasing even terms increasing.

We also have $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$.

So I think the sequence converges in this case. But I'm not sure how to find the limit.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The usual idea is to assume that a limit exists and then determine what it then must be (that's very easy in this case).  Of course, that does not prove that the limit exists but perhaps you have shown that?  (what you wrote does not constitute a proof but it should be that hard to improve it).

Comment: Should note:  it's very easy to determine the limit here just by writing out the first few terms.  Again, that doesn't prove much, but it does provide a lot of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a different proof to Igors.

---

Let us look at the following difference

$$\|x_{n+1} - x_n\| = \left\|\frac{1}{2+x_n} - \frac{1}{2+x_{n-1}}\right\| = \left\|\frac{x_{n-1}-x_n}{(2+x_n)(2+x_{n-1})}\right\| \le \frac{1}{4}\|x_{n-1}-x_n\|.$$

Where the last inequality follows from the fact that $x_n \ge 0$ for all $n$.

Thus, we see that the sequence is convergent.

For the limit $x^*$ we have that

$$ x^* = \frac{1}{2+x^*}.$$

Solving the above we see that $x^* = -1 \pm \sqrt{2}$. Thus, our limit point is $\sqrt{2}-1$.

---

The above argument at a high level uses the idea that the map $T(x) = \frac{1}{2+x}$ is a contraction map on $[0, \infty)$. Hence has a unique fixed point.

Comment: A nice argument, but I am not sure about the word "using" - after all, you are PROVING that the map is a contraction map :)

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Assume the limit exists, and is equal to $L.$ Then $L = \frac{1}{2+L}.$ I assume you can solve that equation. Call the solution $L.$ Now, if $x_n = L + \epsilon,$ show that $|x_{n+1} - L| < \epsilon.$ It is tedious, but works. A slicker way is to express $x_{n+2}$ in terms of $x_n,$ and note that this is given by a linear fractional transformation, which is given by a $2\times2$ matrix, so the proof is easy. However, I assume this is not something you are supposed to know, so do it in the tedious way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L=\sqrt{2}-1$. It is the only nonnegative root of the equation $x=\frac{1}{2+x}$.

Clearly the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$. If it does not converge to $L$, it will have a subsequence that is bounded away from $L$. In turn, some subsequence of this subsequence will converge to some $L'\in[0,1]$ (because $[0,1]$ is compact) but $L'\ne L$ (because this subsequence is bounded away from $L$). Consequently, $L'$ is a second nonnegative root of $x=\frac{1}{2+x}$. This is impossible. Hence $\{x_n\}$ must converge to $L$.